# Failed to connect to server "xxx" but works in Visual Studio Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smo

I am trying to backup a database on a remote development server and send it to a network drive folder that is shared between mine and the development pc.

I have attached the function I'm calling and the error that I am getting too.

However when I run this using the Visual Studio Start button in the top it works perfectly fine (When running in admin mode)

Everyone keeps saying permissions but I dont understand how the permissions on my pc will be taken into account on the development server

```
public static string BackupDatabase(string DatabaseName)
        {
            String sqlServerLogin = Properties.Resources.Username;
            String password = Properties.Resources.Password;
            String remoteSvrName = Properties.Resources.DataSource;

            // Authentication
            ServerConnection srvConn2 = new ServerConnection(remoteSvrName);
            srvConn2.LoginSecure = false;
            srvConn2.Login = sqlServerLogin;
            srvConn2.Password = password;
            
            // Initialisation of the server object
            Server srv = new Server(srvConn2);

            Backup bk = new Backup();
            bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            bk.BackupSetDescription = "Staging Transfer";
            bk.BackupSetName = DatabaseName + " Backup";
            bk.Database = DatabaseName;

            // Declare a BackupDeviceItem by supplying the backup device file name in the constructor, and the type of device is a file.   
            BackupDeviceItem bdi = default(BackupDeviceItem);
            string backupPath = Properties.Resources.DatabaseBackupPath + DatabaseName + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".bak";
            if (File.Exists(backupPath))
            {
                File.Delete(backupPath);
            }
            bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(backupPath, DeviceType.File);
            // Add the device to the Backup object.   
            bk.Devices.Add(bdi);

            bk.Checksum = true;
            bk.ContinueAfterError = true;
            bk.Initialize = true;
            // Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup.   
            bk.Incremental = false;
           
            // Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.   
            bk.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

            // Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server.   
            bk.SqlBackup(srv);
            bk.Wait();

            return backupPath;
        }
```

Is anyone able to advise me on this? It's driving me crazy!

```
private void backupDatabaseWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            backupDatabaseWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            Utilities util = new Utilities();
            string database = util.GetDatabase(filePathSelected.Text);
            string backupReturn = SQL.BackupDatabase(database);
            backupPath = backupReturn;
            MessageBox.Show(database);
            MessageBox.Show(backupReturn);
        }
```

The GetDatabase function works fine, that uses the web config to grab the database name that the site uses.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Error

```
Failed to connect to server dev.   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.PoolConnect()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.GetServerInformation()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetServerVersion()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.get_ServerVersion()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup.Script(Server targetServer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup.SqlBackup(Server srv)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup.SqlBackup(Server srv)
   at PCS_Lithium.SQL.BackupDatabase(String DatabaseName)
   at PCS_Lithium.PushToStagingForm.backupDatabaseWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
```